# How can I get a pytorch Tensor containing some other Tensor's size (or shape) without conversion to Python int?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

In the context of exporting pytorch code to ONNX, I get this warning:

TracerWarning: torch.tensor results are registered as constants in the trace. You can safely ignore this warning if you use this function to create tensors out of constant variables that would be the same every time you call this function. In any other case, this might cause the trace to be incorrect.

Here is the offending line:

```
text_lengths = torch.tensor([text_inputs.shape[1]]).long().to(text_inputs.device)
```

`text_inputs` is a `torch.Tensor` of shape `torch.Size([1, 81])`

And the warning is spot on and cannot be ignored, because the shape of `text_inputs` is supposed to be dynamic.

I need `text_lengths` to be a `torch.Tensor` that contains the number `81` coming from the `shape` of `text_inputs`. The "offending line" from above succeeds in doing that, but we actually make a round trip from pytorch to a Python `int` and back to pytorch, because the elements in the `torch.Size` objects are Python `int`s. This is (1) somewhat weird, (2) probably inefficient in terms of GPU -> CPU -> GPU and, as stated above, an actual problem in the ONNX exporting context.

Is there some other way how I can use a tensor's shape in torch computations, without "leaving" the torch world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** As was pointed out in the comments, the original answer was incorrect.

Using `torch.tensor` will lead to a constant value in the exported graph. When tracing, outputs of `torch.tensor.shape` and `torch.tensor.size` should return tensors (instead of python integers), so the code above should export as intended just with

```py
text_lengths = text_inputs.shape[1]
```

returning a `LongTensor` with the correct value.

<s>Seems that the code doesn't behave as intended because of the brackets in the constructor. The shape inside of `[text_inputs.shape[1]]` gets interpreted as an integer inside of a  python list, and consequently saved as a constant during the trace.</s>

Dropping the extra brackets when creating the tensor will export correctly as a scalar defined at runtime by the shape of `text_inputs` .

```py
text_lengths = torch.LongTensor(text_inputs.size(1))
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.
Your `torch.LongTensor(text_inputs.size(1))` doesn't yield the required result; that produces a tensor of size 81 (in my example above), but I need a tensor of size 1 containing the number 81. Hence I need the square brackets.

Your answer pointed me in a good direction, though. Switching from
`text_lengths = torch.tensor([text_inputs.shape[1]]).long().to(text_inputs.device)`
to
`text_lengths = torch.LongTensor([text_inputs.shape[1]]).to(text_inputs.device)`
makes it work. Apparently the ONNX tracer does not like the cast in the original line...
Thank you!

Comment: I'll accept your answer, although both its reasoning and suggested solution are technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! You are absolutely right, my answer is incorrect. Funnily enough, the variable `text_length` gets the wrong value when executed in `pytorch`, but the intended one in the resulting graph after `torch.onnx.export`. I suspect this due to `torch.LongTensor(tensor)` being a no-op in `TorchScript`.

Comment: After a more in-depth read of the documentation, it turned out that `torch.Tensor.shape` always returns a `LongTensor` in `TorchScript`. So technically you don't even need to initialize and cast the dimension shape, the bare `text_inputs.shape[1]` should work. I will update my answer, though please do unaccept it if I still get it wrong.


Also note that with your solution, `text_lengths` will still get exported as a constant when using `torch.jit.trace`.